# How does Tollen’s reagent reacts with hydroxylamine?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation, nitro-compounds

How does the Tollens' reagent react with hydroxyl amines? For example, let's consider phenylhydroxylamine $\ce{Ph-NH-OH}$ reaction with Tollens' reagent. First it yields $\ce{Ph-N=O}$ and on further oxidation, $\ce{Ph-NO2}$

There’s no carbonyl bond for O radical generation. How does it proceeds then? I could not find its mechanism online.

Comment: Why would you need some carbonyl bond? N-O radicals are created very easily. Hydrogen, like, barely holds onto oxygen.